# Windows NT binary executable file internal const string encoding

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding, windows-nt

Windows NT uses the Unicode (two bytes wide UTF-16) as the default encoding method throughout the Windows NT API. If you choose to use ASCII or multibyte character set as your default character set, they will transform ASCII to Unicode. And use ASCII character set will be slower than Unicode.
What does this transform mean? They only transform ASCII API to Unicode API or transform all the strings?
For example:
If you create a C/C++ file with `const char* text = "Hello, world!"`. When you compile it on Windows NT, does the compiled binary file store "Hello, world!" as Unicode (26 bytes) or ASCII (13 bytes)?

Answer (score 2):

You have to decide which API version you use: ANSI or Unicode.  Either you use the functions explicitly (like CreateFileA for ANSI, resp. CreateFileW for Unicode) or you use the function name without 'A' or 'W' and the _UNICODE preprocessor variable decides which of the two functions is used.  Certain functions require structs that contain strings. Then there are two versions of these structs as well (like OSVERSIONINFOA and OSVERSIONINFOW). There is no good reason to ANSI nowadays.

But this only applies to **arguments**, not content.  If you write a string to a file using a pointer to the data and its size, no translation is taking place.

To answer your question: since you explicitly used `char` it takes up 13 bytes.  If you'd used `wchar` it would use 26 bytes. You could have written `const TCHAR* text = _T("Hello world!");` and then _UNICODE would decide.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't change the type of your strings. It will encode them as you declare them.

Windows NT and its subsequent versions (2000, XP, 2003, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, 10) internally use 2-byte characters (it calls them "wide characters"). Windows NT used to use the [`UCS-2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte_order_encoding_schemes) encoding; since Windows 2000 it switched to `UTF-16LE`.

For most of its API functions that handle strings they have 2 different versions; the name of the one that handles ANSI strings ends in `A`, the name of the other one ends in `W` ("W" from "wide chars"). A set of macro definitions maps the names without suffixes to either the `A` or the `W` versions. The selection is driven by the presence of a macro named `_UNICODE`. The programmer is, however, free to call the `A` or the `W` function directly, if the situation calls for it.

In order to help the developers handle wide character strings, the standard C library provided by Microsoft contains a set of functions for handling wide-char strings (the equivalents of `strlen()`, `strcat()` a.s.o). Their names usually have `str` replaced with `wcs`.

The programmer is the one that decides which version of each function to use. Most of the times there is no need to convert the encoding (as long as you stick to one of the above). However, there are subsystems where there are no options: you have to convert the strings to Unicode to make them work.

You can read more about how Windows handles the strings in the API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

To answer your question, Windows doesn't change your strings. It only converts internally from ANSI to Unicode the strings to pass to the `A` versions of its API functions. It also converts from Unicode back to ANSI (if possible), the strings that are returned by the `A` versions of the API functions ([`GetWindowTextA()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for example).

Comment: Actually, WinNT used UCS-2, it was in Win2000 when Microsoft switched to UTF-16.

Comment: And, "A" is for ANSI, not ASCII. ANSI being the selected code page for the thread at the time of the API call.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are right. I updated the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @TomBlodget you are right. The "ASCII" from the question got stuck into my mind and it found its way into the response. I corrected it now. Thank you.